# install Spark issue. Cannot open IPython Notebook with pyspark

Tags: installation, apache-spark, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pyspark

Here is the link to the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8DOl.png

I am trying to get a standalone installation of spark working but I am getting this error. I set JAVA_HOME in my environmental variables to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31".

After I type pyspark, ipthon notebook should open up in a new tab but it does not.

It seems that it cannot find something with 'notebook' in it but not sure

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Windows is a disaster.  Install [ubuntu server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) on a [VM](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and run Spark/IPython from there.  It will make your life stress free.

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2.5 hours the problem was set IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook" should of been  IPYTHON_OPTS=notebook. no quotes.

Comment: i wasn't able to run pyspark on my notebook. when i run the following:IPYTHON_OPTS=notebook ./bin/pyspark, it says IPYTHON_OPTS is not recognised as an internal or external command

Answer (score 0):

Since you have been executing in Window you would need to first set the IPYTHON_OPTS variable and then execute the command to startup pyspark

1. set IPYTHON_OPTS=notebook
2. ./bin/pyspark

Answer (score 0):

I've tried that method as well; it won't work. I've used the following on Windows 10 and 7 successfully, using Enthought Canopy as my IDE and IPython notebooks.

Step 1. Check your environment variables for Python and Spark. Can you launch pyspark directly from a command prompt?

Step 2. Launch Python (or IPython)

Step 3. Use (and adjust to your machine) the following code:

```
import os

import sys

spark_home = os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None)

if not spark_home:

raise ValueError('SPARK_HOME environment variable is not set')

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python'))

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'C:/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip'))

execfile(os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/pyspark/shell.py'))
```

If you followed my steps, you should get spark up and running.

[pyspark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qiFW.png)